# Ruby on Rails if statement not working, although variable has a Boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
      <% if @property.for_sale? %>
    <%= @property.price > 0 ? number_to_currency(@property.price, precision: 0) : "For Sale" %>
  <% else %>
     <%= @property.price > 0 ? number_to_currency(@property.price, precision: 0) : "For Rent" %> / month
  <% end %>
```

for_sale variable is set to false

```
Parameters: { "for_sale"=>"false", "id"=>"3"}
```

This is the code that sets it to false:

```
<%= form.select :for_sale, options_for_select({ "Yes" => true, "No" => false }
```

Therefore the else statement should run. However, this is not reflected on the view side. What am I missing here?

## edit 1

"for_sale" variable is set to true by default.

```
t.boolean "for_sale", default: true
```

However, when I change it to false with the options_for_select code shown above it still remains as true.

Any clue why?

## edit 2

Solved it! for_sale variable was not included in property_params

```
def property_params
  params.require(:property).permit(:name, :address, :price, :rooms, :bathrooms, :parking_spaces,:details, :photo, :photo_cache, :for_sale)
end
```

Comment: have you tried to print the type of `false` to make sure that you receive it as boolean?

Comment: Using `"false"` would run a truthiness check, and for that case simply by being a string, it'll take the true "path" of your if condition. In that case, check just if `@property.for_sale?` == 'false' (or 'true').

Comment: @SebastianPalma This worked. Thanks! I still cannot understand, however, why "false" is a string, although the code clearly generates a boolean?

Comment: In HTML there is no such thing really as `true` and `false`, it is all just text. `options_for_select` is creating something like this `<option value="true">Yes</option>, and its `value` will be interpreted in Ruby as a string. Similar can be said for numbers (eg. `value="1"`)

Comment: Because everything that's converted to params becomes a string after all @SantiagoCepeda.

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle the case of `'false'` being a string OR a boolean value of `false` would be to typecast the value. Since you're using Rails you can do:

```
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(@property.for_sale)
```

This will ensure that both `'false'` and `false` evaluate to `false`

Comment: That would be your if statement. So `<% if ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(@property.for_sale) %>`